# Blazor UI hanging during memory file upload

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorinputfile

I'm working on a simple blazor application that receives a file upload and stores it.  I am using  [BlazorInputFile](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile) and I can't work out why copying the stream to MemoryStream is causing the browser to freeze.

The details of how to use (and how it's implemented) [BlazorInputFile](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile) are explained in this blog post: **[Uploading Files in Blazor](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/341/uploading-files-in-blazor)**.

```
 var ms = new MemoryStream();
 await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms); // With a 1MB file, this line took 3 seconds, and froze the browser

 status = $"Finished loading {file.Size} bytes from {file.Name}";
```

Sample project/repo: https://github.com/paulallington/BlazorInputFileIssue
(this is just the default Blazor app, with BlazorInputFile implemented as per the article)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Blazor/Wasm

Comment: How odd, I can consistently reproduce now.  I tracked it down, it looks like it might actually a bug in blazor, I've just seen an issue on github.  The StateHasChanged is a hangover from the bigger app I think, sorry copy and paste issue :)

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm attempting to load an ~`5MB` file and everything just freezes indefinitely...

Comment: @WBuck I sort of gave up in the end, and tried the RadZen file uploader - it works really well, and has nice progress indicators on it as well

Comment: that’s funny, I ended up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `await Task.Delay(1);` as mentioned on Zhi Lv's comment in this post [blazor-webassembly upload file can't show progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64765560/blazor-webassembly-upload-file-cant-show-progress)

```cs
var buffer = new byte[imageFile.Size];
await Task.Delay(1);

await imageFile.OpenReadStream(Int64.MaxValue).ReadAsync(buffer);

pratica.Files.Add(new FilePraticaRequest()
{
    Contenuto = buffer,
    Nome = imageFile.Name,

});
StateHasChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue. I've tried both predefined components such as Steve Sanderssons file upload and MatBlazor fileupload and also my own component to handle fileuploads. Small files are not a problem. Once the files are a bit larger in size the UI will hang itself. MemoryOutOfBoundsException (or similar). So no, async/await can't help you release the UI. 
I have put so much effort into this issue, one solution, that I am currently using, is to do all fileuploads with javascript instead of blazor. Just use javascript to get the file and post it up to the server. No JSInterop.. 
However, it seems like it is a memory issue in webassembly mono. 
Read more here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15777

**Note:** I haven't tried this on the latest Blazor version. So I'm not sure it's fixed or not.

Comment: It's not, I tried it too.  It lead me to discover the Radzen file uploader - that works *very* well...like you I've spent WAY too long trying to work it out, hehe

Answer (score 0):

You wait for the copy result, so the app freeze, you can refactor your code like this;

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();
file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms).ContinueWith(async task => 
{
   if (task.Exception != null)
   {
      throw task.Exception; // Update this by your convenience
   }
   status = $"Finished loading {file.Size} bytes from {file.Name}";
   await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).ConfigureAwait(false); // informs the component the status changed
}; // With a 1MB file, this line took 3 seconds, and should not froze the browser
```

Comment: Alas that doesn't make a difference.  The screen still freezes.  I *think* it might actually be a problem with Blazor itself

Comment: Did you try when compiled in Release mode ? It can be a debugger or compilation options issue.

Comment: It looks like it's actually a bug in blazor, I've just seen an issue on github.  thank you though